# Swift 3 - Get value from core data

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3, one-to-one

I have a class that will take 2 inputs, Sets and Reps

Using prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) I passed the values back to the WorkoutViewController.Swift

The data is successfully saved since after pressing save barbutton in the SetRepsViewController.Swift the window pops

However the labels do not show the values
What am I doing wrong here
I believe that targetLog?.setAndrep?.sets is not correctly getting the value

Can someone please help me on what I should do?

Screenshow of the viewController [image: viewController]

WorkoutViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class WorkoutViewController: UIViewController{

var muscleLog: MuscleList?
var targetLog: Log?


@IBOutlet weak var LogTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var weightInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var repsInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dateView: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var setsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var repsLabel: UILabel!


let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

func workoutTitle(title: String){
    self.title = title

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    let date = Date()
    let dateInPersian = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    dateView.text = dateInPersian



}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {



    setsLabel.text = targetLog?.repLog?.sets
    repsLabel.text = targetLog?.setAndrep?.reps

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "addTarget"{
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? SetRepsViewController else {
            return
        }
        destination.destLog = targetLog
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//hide keybaord method
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}



@IBAction func addLog(_ sender: Any) {

    let weight = Double(weightInput.text ?? "") ?? 0.0
    let reps = Int16(repsInput.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let todayDate = dateView.text ?? ""
    let notes = input.text ?? ""

    if let log = Log(weight: weight, reps: reps, currentday: todayDate, notes: notes){
        muscleLog?.addToDailyLogs(log)

        do{
            try log.managedObjectContext?.save()
        }catch {
            print("Could not Log")
        }
    }
    LogTableView.reloadData()

}


func deleteMuscle(at indexPath: IndexPath){
    guard let logs = muscleLog?.logList?[indexPath.row],
        let managedContext = logs.managedObjectContext else{
            return
    }
    managedContext.delete(logs)

    do{
        try managedContext.save()

        LogTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

    }catch{
        print("Could not save")
        LogTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}

 }


 extension WorkoutViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return muscleLog?.logList?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let WorkCell = LogTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WorkCell", for: indexPath)

    if let logs = muscleLog?.logList?[indexPath.row] {
        WorkCell.textLabel?.text = logs.currentday

        let weight = String(logs.weight)
        let reps = String(logs.reps)
        let note = logs.notes

        WorkCell.detailTextLabel?.text = weight + " kg x " + reps + " reps  Notes: "+note!
    }

    return WorkCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        deleteMuscle(at: indexPath)
    }
}

}
```

SetRepsViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class SetRepsViewController: UIViewController {

var destLog: Log?

@IBOutlet weak var setText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var repText: UITextField!



@IBAction func saveTarget(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    let sets = setText.text ?? ""
    let reps = repText.text ?? ""

    if let target = SetRep(sets: sets, reps: reps){
        destLog?.addsetAndrep(target)
        do{
            try target.managedObjectContext?.save()

            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }catch{
            print("Could not save workout")
        }
    }
}





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Comment: You should set the labels in `viewWillAppear` not `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @pbasdf I put it in viewWillApear as well but didnt work

Comment: How are `destLog` and `targetLog` declared and populated?

Comment: @pbasdf
Using the prepare for segue function
      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "addTarget"{
            guard let destination = segue.destination as? SetRepsViewController else {
                return
            }
            destination.destLog = targetLog
        }
        
        
    }

Comment: Is targetLog == nil?  How do you set it?

Comment: @pbasdf in my WorkoutViewController.swift I have declared it as var targetLog: Log?

Comment: OK - but how and where do you assign a value to it?

Comment: @pbasdf I haven't, what I did was assign a value to destLog and using targetLog I am trying to access it, Unless what Im doing is wrong?

Comment: @pbasdf I have updated my question to show my entire class for WorkoutViewController.swift and SetRepsViewController.swift perhaps it will help you

Answer (score 1):

@IMan after saving the data in core data  you will have to fetch the data from CoreData then you can show your data.

Comment: Do you know how I can fetch the data, I have tried in many ways, I am not sure how to fetch data that is a One to One relation

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value for `destLog` in your `prepareForSegue` by determining which row has been selected in your tableView:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addTarget"{
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? SetRepsViewController else {
            return
        }
        let indexPath = LogTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        targetLog = muscleLog?.logList?[indexPath.row]
        destination.destLog = targetLog
    }
}
```

That will ensure that the Log corresponding to the selected row in your table view is passed to the SetRepsViewController.  When you dismiss the SetRepsViewController, the `viewWillAppear` code will update the labels correctly as `targetLog` and `destLog` both refer to the same Log object.

Comment: It gives Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Which element in the scene is the segue hooked up to?  I assumed it was the prototype cell?

Answer (score 0):

@IMan Try this

func fetchList() {

```
 let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<"YOUR ENTITY NAME"> = ("YOUR ENTITY NAME").fetchRequest()

    do {
        let fetchResults = try self.moc.fetch(fetchRequest)

        for Entity in fetchResults as [NSManagedObject] {

            let entity1 = Entity.value(forKey: "YOUR ENTITY KEY VALUE") 
            let entity12 = Entity.value(forKey: "YOUR ENTITY KEY VALUE") 


   print(entity1, entity2)



    } catch {

        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```